# se2jekyll.rb—export Stack Exchange posts for use on Jekyll blogs

Tags: app, ruby

### Synopsis

```
se2jekyll.rb site post_id
```

Example (https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3020):

```
$ se2jekyll.rb Meta.Puzzling 3020 > site_evaluations.md
```

Republished at: http://jericson.github.io/2015/05/15/site_evaluations.html

### Source

The project is hosted [on GitHub](https://github.com/jericson/se2jekyll.rb):

> https://github.com/jericson/se2jekyll.rb/blob/master/se2jekyll.rb

### Dependencies

This is my very first Ruby program, so you have to have [Ruby installed](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/documentation/installation/). I've included a [Gemfile](http://bundler.io/gemfile.html) with required libraries, so you should be able to install all other dependencies with:

```
$ bundle install
```

(If you haven't used Bundler before, you'll need to run `gem install bundler` first.)

Comment: Nice script. I think that at this stage of learning ruby, it is very helpful to post your code at codereview. You will learn a lot.